# Change element values while ignoring xmlns

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a XML file with a `xmlns` tag like this:

```
xmlns:mis20="http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20"

<mis20:number>194803040000</mis20:number>
```

This is how I read the element right now

```
var numberList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("mis20:number");
```

I want to be able to read it like this

```
var numberList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("number");
```

Comment: Bad idea - the XML namespace is there **for a good reason**  - and you should *not* just ignore it. You need to instead **learn how to work with XML namespaces** in whatever language/programming system you're working in....

Comment: What do you mean, you want to "ignore" it? this declares a namespace alias; if you "ignore" it, then `mis20:whatever` will be meaningless. Can you perhaps add more context as to what you're trying to do here?

Comment: I've realised it might be hard to ignore the whole namespace, but how about including it in the reading somehow?

Comment: This is how i do it now ;: var numberList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("mis20:number");

Comment: i want to be able to only write "number" as such var numberList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("number"); But i have to save the namespace into a variabel somehow, and the namespaces can be diffrent in each xmlfile so a substring wouldnt work

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **add** the XML namespace "URL" to the call you're making:

```
// just add the XML namespace "url" in this call
var numberList = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("number", "http://www.mis.sfm.se/mis20");

if (numberList != null)
{
    XmlNode node = numberList[0];

    int value = -1;

    if (int.TryParse(node.Value, out value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your value is: {0}", value);
    }
}
```